# Python class inheritance (multiple) : Why are attributes empty? i.e. doing it right

Tags: python, class, inheritance, mixins

I'm trying create an intermediate object to work with elsewhere that I can pass in to an sqlalchemy model for creation:

start with:

```
class IntermediateObj(object):

    def __init__(self, raw):
        self.raw = raw
        self.sections = []
        self.fields = []
        self.elements = []
        super(IntermediateObj, self).__init__()

    def recurse(self, items):
        for k,v in items.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                getattr(self, k).append(v)
                [self.recurse(i) for i in v]
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)
```

pass to:

```
class MyClass(IntermediateObj, Base):

    def __init__:(self, attribute=None):
         self.attribute = attribute 
         super(MyClass, self).__init__
```

e.g.

```
ii = IntermediateObj(raw={'large':'nested_dictionary', sections=[{}, {}, {}]})
ii.recurse(ii.raw) #any help smoothing this bit over appreciated as well, but another question...
tada = MyClass(ii)

tada.sections
---> [] /// this should not be, it should correspond to ii.sections
```

Sections is empty where it should not be, so I don't quite grasp inheritance here yet. This has to be a common question, but I have not found anything I could understand at this point and am just flailing around at various tactics. Any input appreciated on doing python class inheritance correctly.

Comment: You never append to `sections`, why should it change?

Comment: Actually I glossed over the nested dictionary part "getattr(self, k).append(v)" actually does append sections, fields, and elements when it runs into those. UNLESS I'm not doing/setting that right

Comment: How is `MyClass.__init__()` defined?

Comment: Myclass.__init() rough sketch added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class IntermediateObj(object):

    def __init__(self, raw):
        self.raw = raw
        self.sections = []
        self.fields = []
        self.elements = []

    def recurse(self, items):
        # this works ok, but passing the same arguments to the recurse function
        # which were passed to the constructor as well ,and then stored as a class
        # attribute, why, seems like self.raw is not even needed?
        for k,v in items.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                getattr(self, k).append(v)
                [self.recurse(i) for i in v]
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)


class MyClass(IntermediateObj):

    def __init__(self, attribute=None):  
        self.attribute = attribute
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(attribute)


ii = IntermediateObj({'large': 'nested_dictionary',
                      'sections': [{}, {}, {}]
                    })
ii.recurse(ii.raw)
print ii.raw
print ii.sections

# passing an instance of IntermediateObj is not the same as passing a dict (logically)
# yet the constructor of MyClass just forwards that instance object to the
# baseclasses constructor, while you initially passed a dict to the IntermediateObj
# constructor. 
tada = MyClass(ii)
# MyClass inherits the recurse method, but it won't magically be executed unless
# you call it, so just instantiating MyClass won't copy those values recursively
tada.recurse(ii.raw)
# now tada, it copied everything, and notice, I called recurse with ii.raw, which is the
# source dictionary, but I'm not even sure if you wanted it that way, it's not clear
# define your question more precisely
print tada.sections
```

I see you have accepted this as the best answer, and I felt bad about it cause it's not really answered, so I made an update, as we described in the comments, now when an instance of MyClass receives an instance of IntermediateObj, it will call the constructor of the base class with the raw parameter of the passed object. Also recurse is called in IntermediateObj's constructor, so it will copy the values at instantiation time:

```
class IntermediateObj(object):

    def __init__(self, raw):
        self.raw = raw
        self.sections = []
        self.fields = []
        self.elements = []
        self.recurse(raw)

    def recurse(self, items):
        for k,v in items.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                getattr(self, k).append(v)
                [self.recurse(i) for i in v]
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)


class MyClass(IntermediateObj):

    def __init__(self, intermediate_instance):  
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(intermediate_instance.raw)


ii = IntermediateObj({'large': 'nested_dictionary',
                      'sections': [{}, {}, {}]
                    })
print ii.raw
print ii.sections
tada = MyClass(ii)
print tada.sections
print tada.raw
```

Comment: ok, so if want an attribute from an inherited instance to be accessible in the enclosing instance, I need to explicitly set this?

Comment: a class that inherits from another class will get all the base class attributes, and all values which are available at the class definition.a class can't get values from an instance through inheritance, it must be passed to it. I will modify this example to your needs, just to sort out: MyClass inherits all IntermediateObj class attributes/methods, then you create an instance of IntermediateObj, and an instance of MyClass. You want to pass an instance of IntermediateObj to an instance of MyClass, and that MyClass instance must collect all the values available from the intermediateObj instance?

Comment: ok, I'm working with what I'd like to happen and what I've done before. I was not aware that I could not inherit instance values with a new class -- but this is what I'd like to do, or learn to do what I need to do pythonically.